# Targeting the ID of a nested field in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm using the dependent-fields-rails gem to show/hide fields in a form. Mostly, it's working really well! However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to target fields that are nested because dependent-fields-rails requires an ID to target (ID in the CSS/JS sense), and these have identifiers that I don't know how to predict/code for.

Example:

A user has_many credit cards. I want to be able to show US states or Canadian provinces depending on which value the user has selected for that field, when inputting credit card billing address.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
...user info fields...
<div>
        <%= f.fields_for :credit_cards do |card| %>
          <%= render 'shared_partials/credit_card_fields', f: card %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Credit Card', f, :credit_cards, partial: 'shared_partials/credit_card_fields' %>
      </div>
    <%= f.submit "Save and Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

In the credit cards partial:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
        <%= f.text_field :card_holder_first_name, :label => "Card Holder First Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :card_holder_last_name, :label => 'Card Holder Last Name' %>
        <%= f.select :card_type, ["Master Card", "American Express","VISA"] %>
        <%= f.text_field :card_number, :label => 'Card Number', placeholder: 'Must be 15 or 16 digits long.' %>
        <%= f.text_field :ccv, :label => 'CCV Number' %>
        <%= f.date_select :expiration_date, as: :date_select, order: [:month, :year] %>
        <%= f.select :country, [["USA", "USA"],["Canada","Canada"]] %>
        <%= f.text_field :street_address %>
        <%= f.text_field :city %>
        <div class="js-dependent-fields" data-select-id='user_credit_cards_attributes_country' data-option-value='USA'>
        <%= f.select :state, us_states %>  
    </div>
```

```
    <%= f.text_field :zip %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Credit Card", f %> <br>
        <hr />
    </div>
```

The issue here is that I can't figure out how to target the ID of the country selection field. You can see I've tried "user_credit_cards_attributes_country," but that doesn't work. When I view source, the ID is something like: id="user_credit_cards_attributes_1467770518320_country"
The number in the middle changes every time.
I know this is because I'm doing this in a fields_for context, but I don't know how to target an ID that is dynamic that way. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just add a custom `class` attribute that you then use for your CSS/JS, so something like:

```
<%= f.select :country, [["USA", "USA"],["Canada","Canada"]], class: 'country-dropdown' %>
```

That should provide you with the predictable selector `.country-dropdown`.